# Factoring out an Exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to know whether or not I can factor out an exponent on 2 variables like so

$A^2 * B^2 = (A*B)^2$ ?

Comment: Yes, indeed.  :)

Comment: For real numbers (and many other objects), yes. (Since this is tagged as precalculus, and precalculus curricula sometimes include matrices, it's perhaps worth noting that this does *not* generally hold if $A$ and $B$ are matrices.)

Answer (score 3):

Let us expand the terms
$$
A^2 B^2 = A A B B \\
(A B)^2 = (AB)(AB) = ABAB
$$
So it is the same, if your numbers are commutative ($A B = B A$).

Answer (score 1):

As I tell my college algebra students inumerable times:
You can distribute an exponent over multiplication and division:
$$(ab)^n=a^nb^n,\left(\frac ab\right)^n=\frac{a^n}{b^n},$$

but you cannot distribute an exponent over addition or subtraction:
$$(a+b)^n\ne a^n+b^n, (a-b)^n\ne a^n-b^n.$$

Comment: I thought you add the exponents in that case IE

$A^2 * B^2 = (A*B)^4$ and not $A^2 * B^2 = (A*B)^2$

Comment: No, you can only add exponents when the bases are the same.  $A^2A^3=A^5$.

Comment: I see, thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Sure thing! I teach this stuff all the time.